# How to stop the cursor after the text is finished

Tags: css, animation, typing

I have a typewriting effect on my webpage but it has a little problem. After the text finished typing the blinking cursor keeps moving to the end of the line. How do I make it stay after the last letter?

It's basic but maybe I need to add something more or modify it?

```css
.typewriter h1{
  position: relative;
  top: 7em;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(100, end),
            blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing{
  from {width: 0}
  to {width: 100%}
}

@keyframes blink-caret{
  from, to {border-color: transparent}
  50% {border-color: white}
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
    <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello :). Can you add your (relevant) HTML too to create an example for us? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve That would help a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the width of your `.typewriter h1` is set to 100%.

Use `max-width` and set the `width` to `auto` and `display` to `inline-block`.

```css
.typewriter h1{
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(100, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing{
  from {max-width: 0}
  to {max-width: 100%}
}

@keyframes blink-caret{
  from, to {border-color: transparent}
  50% {border-color: black}
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
    <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Could you mark the answer as Accepted so others can see it worked for you :)

Comment: Sure will do :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do this as following by adding an inline element inside h1.And exploiting the after pseudo element property.
Hope, it helps.

```css
.typewriter h1{
position: relative;
width: fit-content;
overflow: hidden;
border-right: .15em solid white;
white-space: nowrap;
margin: 0 auto;
letter-spacing: .15em;
animation: typing 3.5s steps(100, end),
            blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing{
from {width: 0}
to {width: 100%}
}
span:after{
  content : '-';
  animation:blinking .75s step-end infinite;
  color  :transparent;
  display : inline-block;
  width  :5px;
}
@keyframes blink-caret{
from, to {border-color: transparent}
50% {border-color: white}
}
@keyframes blinking{
from, to {background: transparent;}
50% {background: black;}
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
    <h1>Welcome to my website <span></span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that didn't really do it. It just drew a small black line after the last letter but the cursor still goes to the end of the line.